# Java API Error: org.apahe.hadoop.hbase does not exist

Tags: hbase, java

My HBase is version 1.1.3 and I can do CRUD operations using the Hbase Shell.

I am trying to use the Java API to do CRUD operations on HBase.I am using Netbeans and have done Properties>Libraries>add JAR/Folder , and have added the entire lib folder from Hbase_home/lib.

Still, I am getting the error that my import files do not exist...

I am importing these:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Put;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes;
```

Another note:
I had read online that these are the exact jar files needed to use the Java API for HBase are:

```
─ commons-configuration-1.8.jar
├── commons-lang-2.6.jar
├── commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
├── hadoop-core-1.0.0.jar
├── hbase-0.92.1.jar
├── log4j-1.2.16.jar
├── slf4j-api-1.5.8.jar
├── slf4j-log4j12-1.5.8.jar
└── zookeeper-3.4.3.jar
```

BUT, my HBase 1.1.3 does not contain any **hadoop-core-1.0.0.jar** or **hbase-0.92.1.jar**  (or any jar file similar to this). I am thinking this might be the problem...however if my HBase is already working without these files do I need them to make the Java API to work?

Please what can I do?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

ok, i suggest you use Maven Project and add hbase client dependency in your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
    <artifactId>hbase-client</artifactId>
    <version>${hbase.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

good luck to you !